# ASP.NET MVC 5 ajax error statusText is always "error"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem sending a custom message on error to an ajax call. My controller returns something like this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "My error!");
```

And my ajax code looks like this:

```
error: function (xhr, httpStatusMessage) {
              console.log(xhr.statusText);
              console.log(httpStatusMessage);
}
```

The problem is that xhr.statusCode and httpStatusMessage is always "error". What am I doing wrong now?
I'm expecting to have "My error!" in xhr.statusText.

I'm using `ASP.NET MVC 5` and `jquery-1.10.2`

My xhr output is:

```
abort:ƒ ( statusText )
always:ƒ ()
complete:ƒ ()
done:ƒ ()
error:ƒ ()
fail:ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders:ƒ ()
getResponseHeader:ƒ ( key )
overrideMimeType:ƒ ( type )
pipe:ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress:ƒ ()
promise:ƒ ( obj )
readyState:4
responseText:"Bad Request"
setRequestHeader:ƒ ( name, value )
state:ƒ ()
status:400
statusCode:ƒ ( map )
statusText:"error"
success:ƒ ()
then:ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
```

My Web.config httpErrors configuration looks like this:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

and still, on my dev environment, the responseText is empty and the statusText is just "error".

Comment: Check the console for the error. Also check the response text of the request there too as it should give you the exception

Comment: ResponseText is "Bad Request" as you can see.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311074/1132334) is suggesting that you should send an empty `ContentResult` with the custom error message written to the response body. could you show more of what you're doing in the controller part?

Comment: I tried all of that and it still doesn't work. The thing is that I uploaded on azure and there I get the custom message just right so the problem is on my local dev environment.

Comment: look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31040671/1132334) and [this](https://gist.github.com/remi/929007). I guess its one of those settings messing with the custom errors behavior of IIS.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31287090/1132334

Comment: if it was not for the iis version and mvc tags, I'd be tempted to mark this one as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434272/iis7-overrides-customerrors-when-setting-response-statuscode

Answer (score 7):

You need to set a property in your Web.Config file.

Citing a user of [this web page](https://gist.github.com/remi/929007) on github, emphasis mine,

> By default IIS will **mask your error codes and replace them with default errors**. The "PassThrough" option tells IIS to leave your custom errors alone and render them as-is.

"Bad Request" is the default [http error text](https://httpstatuses.com/400) for the status code 400.

So there is the setting as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/) and [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31041696/1132334),

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Consult the documentation carefully for your version of IIS, there is lots of subtle version differences.

**EDIT**

Not really specific to MVC, but it is how I once solved it (part of production code), and what seems to have helped OP as well:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write(new String('_', 513) + "my custom message");
```

This [absurd minimum character limit thing](https://forums.asp.net/post/4892334.aspx) may or may not be needed depending on IIS version. I would too be grateful if somebody could shed a little more light on this underdocumented behavior.

Comment: I had this problem before. Now I remembered that part of the solution was a minimum character limit. Sounds weird, but can you try to make your custom error message longer than 512 characters? just pad with any non-whitespace.

Comment: I tried putting a very big text and I got 
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value]

Comment: argh.
where? in the `HttpStatusCodeResult` constuctor? I looked up my code where I had this and it does not really apply here unfortunately (not an MVC controller), but here goes: `context.Response.Write(new String('_', 513) + "my custom error text");`

Comment: Write a response with the following code in controller: Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Content("message");
this is how I got it to work and it's based on your help.