# Bad Request error returns "error" instead of the error message when https is enabled in IIS

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, https, bad-request

I have an ASP .NET MVC 4 web site hosted on IIS 10.0. The action methods in controllers validate the input and if the input is not proper, the action method returns a Bad Request status code (400) along with error message. The code for this is like below

```
public ActionResult SaveCustomer(Customer customer){
      var message = string.Empty
      var isValid = ValidateCustomer(customer, ref message);
      if (!isValid)
      {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,message);   
      }
      //Remaining code to save customer
}
```

The client side code uses JQuery AJAX requests and is like below

```
var customer = {};
// Code to fill the customer object
$.post('/customer/savecustomer', customer, function (data) {

            alert('Customer saved');

        }).error(function (response) {
            alert(response.statusText);

        });
```

The response.statusText displays the error message set in the action method as long as the site is using http. However once the site is configured with https, the response.statusText returns only "error".
I tried using solution mentioned here but it does not work.
[ASP.NET MVC 5 ajax error statusText is always "error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096060/asp-net-mvc-5-ajax-error-statustext-is-always-error)

When I open Network Tab in the Chrome Developer Tools, this is what I find:

### **With HTTP Enabled**

- **Headers tab**

  Request URL: http://example.com/Customer/SaveCustomer

  Request Method: POST

  Status Code: 400 *Error Message sent from server*

  Remote Address: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:80

  Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
- **Response tab**

  Bad Request

### **With HTTPS Enabled**

- **Headers tab**

  Request URL: https://example.com/Customer/SaveCustomer

  Request Method: POST

  Status Code: 400

  Remote Address: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:443

  Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
- **Response tab**

  Bad Request

The difference between http and https is the error message returned with status code with http and only status code returned with https.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you view the web response in Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab), what is the http status and payload returned for http? https? Please add both to your question (**not** as comments).

Comment: Turns out that it had to do with HTTP 2.0. I turned off HTTP 2.0 and switched to HTTP 1.1. Now the error message is showing as expected. I don't know why HTTP 2.0 would cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/2 only specifies that a status code must be returned. It doesn't support HTTP/1 status code description or version.

> HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.
> [From the HTTP/2 specifications](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1.2.4)